# I can't update the product quantity in session

Tags: php, session

I'm trying to make a shopping cart with PHP.
I can add products to the database, but while I was testing, I have discovered a bug. Quantity of pieces does not change if I add the same one in addition to a previously added product. I just want to increase the amount when it is added again from a previously added product. But I tried two different ways, but I failed. I may be making a mistake.

the point we need to focus on in the code : after comment line =>  "//if item already added to cart. Change quantity in shopping card"

 [My Shopping card ss and var_dump["Session"] is here.](https://image.ibb.co/ixNgxy/Ekran_G_r_nt_s_143.png)
[My Codes is here](https://codeshare.io/5RL1xB)
The first method I try is:

```
//Check if cart is not empty.
if(isset($_SESSION["cart"]))
{
    $item_array_id = array_column($_SESSION["cart"], "product_id");

    //Check if the same items not added to cart.
    if(!in_array($_GET["id"], $item_array_id))
    {

        $item_array = array(
            'product_id' => $_GET["id"],
            'item_name' => $_POST["hidden_name"],
            'product_price' => $_POST["hidden_price"],
            'item_quantity' => $_POST["quantity"]
        );
        $_SESSION["cart"][$count] = $item_array;
        echo '<script>alert("Ürün sepete eklendi.")</script>';
        echo '<script>window.location="product.php"</script>';
    }

    //If item already added to cart change quantity in shopping cart
    else
    {   
        $cnt=0;
        foreach($_SESSION["cart"] as $keys => $values){

            if($values["product_id"]==$_GET["id"]){
                $yeni= $values["item_quantity"]+$_POST["quantity"];
                echo $yeni;
                $item_array = array(
                    'product_id' => $_GET["id"],
                    'item_name' => $_POST["hidden_name"],
                    'product_price' => $_POST["hidden_price"],
                    'item_quantity' => $_POST["quantity"]
                );
                $_SESSION["cart"][$cnt] = $item_array;
            }
            $cnt++;
        }

        echo '<script>alert("Product updated in shoping cart")</script>';
        echo '<script>window.location="product.php"</script>';


    }
}

//if cart is empty. Create SESSION["cart"]
else
{
    $item_array = array(
        'product_id' => $_GET["id"],
        'item_name' => $_POST["hidden_name"],
        'product_price' => $_POST["hidden_price"],
        'item_quantity' => $_POST["quantity"]
    );
    $_SESSION["cart"][0] = $item_array;
    echo '<script>alert("Ürün sepetinize eklendi.")</script>';
    echo '<script>window.location="product.php"</script>';
}
```

The second method I try is:

```
   //Check if cart is not empty.
  if(isset($_SESSION["cart"]))
  {
    $item_array_id = array_column($_SESSION["cart"], "product_id");

    //Check if the same items not added to cart.
    if(!in_array($_GET["id"], $item_array_id))
    {

        $item_array = array(
        'product_id' => $_GET["id"],
        'item_name' => $_POST["hidden_name"],
        'product_price' => $_POST["hidden_price"],
        'item_quantity' => $_POST["quantity"]
        );
        $_SESSION["cart"][$count] = $item_array;
        echo '<script>alert("Ürün sepete eklendi.")</script>';
        echo '<script>window.location="product.php"</script>';
    }

    //If item already added to cart change quantity in shopping cart
    else
    {   
        $cnt=0;
        foreach($_SESSION["cart"] as $keys => $values){

            if($values["product_id"]==$_GET["id"]){

                $_SESSION["cart"][$cnt][$values]=$values["item_quantity"]+$_POST["quantity"];
            }
            $cnt++;
        }

        echo '<script>alert("Ürün güncellendi.")</script>';
        echo '<script>window.location="product.php"</script>';
    }
}

//If cart is empty create SESSION["cart"]
else
{
    $item_array = array(
    'product_id' => $_GET["id"],
    'item_name' => $_POST["hidden_name"],
    'product_price' => $_POST["hidden_price"],
    'item_quantity' => $_POST["quantity"]
    );
    $_SESSION["cart"][0] = $item_array;
    echo '<script>alert("Ürün sepetinize eklendi.")</script>';
    echo '<script>window.location="product.php"</script>';
}
```

Both methods do not change the amount of the product available. can you help me with this ?

Comment: If the product is added to the basket for the first time, there is no problem at all. the problem starts at this point, added before the same product, but if the customer wants to add a few more from the same product, the problem arises. I'm trying to figure this out.

Comment: You can do something like this

$_SESSION["cart"][$cnt][$values]['item_quantity'] += $_POST['quantity']

Comment: First method :  first check where your control is going, in IF or in ELSE?, based on inputs rewrite IF condition

Comment: Annouce me if it works.(i just edited my comment)

Comment: @MitcaVicentiu When I tried your code, I compared it with an error like this:Warning =>>> Illegal offset type in C:\xamp\htdocs\Smart-Cafe\Smart Cafe-Codes\shop.php on line 37

Comment: dear @MangeshSathe my live code share : https://codeshare.io/5RL1xB

Comment: Try $_SESSION["cart"][$cnt]['item_quantity'] += $_POST['quantity']

What you need to access it's this: cart[cart_item][quantity]
This should be the way :-?

Comment: @MitcaVicentiu Yes , thank you very much, my brother 1 day to resolve this error was finally a friendly help.  $_SESSION["cart"][$cnt]['item_quantity'] += $_POST['quantity']

Comment: I will post it as an aswer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$_SESSION["cart"][$cnt]['item_quantity'] += $_POST['quantity']
```